# Formatting a string with a namedtuple

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the variablelist of a namedtuple to format a string efficiently like so:

```
TestResult = collections.namedtuple('TestResults', 'creation_time filter_time total_time')

test = TestResult(1, 2, 3)
string_to_format = '{creation_time}, {filter_time}, {total_time}'.format(test)
```

instead of just writing:

```
string_to_format = '{}, {}, {}'.format(test.creation_time, test.filter_time, test.total_time)
```

If there is a way to do this, would it be considered pythonic?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> string_to_format = '{0.creation_time}, {0.filter_time}, {0.total_time}'.format(test)
>>> string_to_format
'1, 2, 3'
```

Is this Pythonic? I don't know but it does two things that are considered Pythonic: 1. Don't repeat yourself! (`test` occurs only once) and 2. Be explicit! (the names in a namedtuple are there to be used)

Comment: This looks nice, but what does the "0." before field name do? Why doesn't it work without "0."?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`_asdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) method to turn your namedtuple into a dict, and then [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) it with the `**` splat operator:

```
test = TestResult(1, 2, 3)

string_to_format = '{creation_time}, {filter_time}, {total_time}'
print(string_to_format.format(**test._asdict()))
# output: 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was close. You should change

```
'{creation_time}, {filter_time}, {total_time}'.format(test)
```

to

```
'{test.creation_time}, {test.filter_time}, {test.total_time}'.format(test=test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a dictionary and use it as the parameters for `format`:

```
test = TestResult(1, 2, 3)
s = '{creation_time}, {filter_time}, {total_time}'.format(**test._asdict())
print(s)  # 1, 2, 3
```